# SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite

SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error)

```
public ArrayList<String> SelectCOMMUNE(String nom_wilaya,String nom_daira) 
{
    ArrayList<String> commune = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        String value;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Khaled/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PFE/dataBase.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NOM_COMMUNE FROM COMMUNE NATURAL JOIN DAIRA"
                + "NATURAL JOIN WILAYA"
                + "WHERE DAIRA.NOM_DAIRA= \""+nom_daira+"\" AND WILAYA.NOM_WILAYA=\""+nom_wilaya+"\";")) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                value = rs.getString("NOM_COMMUNE");
                System.out.println(rs.getString("NOM_COMMUNE"));
                commune.add(value);
            }
        }
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return commune;
}
```

Comment: I do not see the declaration of `c`?

Comment: it's Connection c ;

Comment: Your code above does not include it. Please edit it for easy to read.

Comment: Let's try to edit the path to your db using \\ instead of / like this: `jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Khaled\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PFE\\dataBase.db`

Comment: Check the syntax of the **actual SQL** that gets executed.  It looks like there will be some spaces between keywords in SQL produced by your code.

Comment: no problem when i execute in CMD

Comment: thnx Stephen C two spaces between keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space when you break your strings into separate lines. Make a habit of adding a space at the front of your concatenated string fragments.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT NOM_COMMUNE FROM COMMUNE NATURAL JOIN DAIRA"
            + " NATURAL JOIN WILAYA"
            + " WHERE DAIRA.NOM_DAIRA= \""+nom_daira+"\" AND WILAYA.NOM_WILAYA=\""+nom_wilaya+"\";"))
```

Unrelated to your problem, but still important-- look into prepared statements to avoid some nasty SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: Also unrelated... it's more widely compatible to use single quotes in SQL for your strings.